# Few queries regarding raw sockets in C

Tags: c, linux, sockets, chat

I want to make a chat room using raw socket in C. I have following problems:

Q 1 : Can I use select function to handle multiple connections in case of raw sockets ?

Q 2 : Port nos in sockets are real ports or logically implemented for various applications on transport layer??

Q 3 : I am having one computer only so using lo ( local loop) as my interface. So the process which is initiating the chat has send first and then receive call, so it's receiving it's own data. How to restrict it?

Any help would be appreciated since that would help me in increasing my confidence on raw sockets.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want this to be a real, usable chat system, **stop**.  Don't use raw sockets.  Huge mistake.

If you are just playing around because you want to put “raw sockets” under the “Experience” section of your résumé, you may read on.

1. You can use the select function to detect when a raw socket has a packet available to receive, and when it can accept a packet to transmit.  You can pass multiple file descriptors to a single call to `select` if you want to check multiple raw sockets (or whatever) simultaneously.
2. Port numbers are part of the TCP and UDP protocols (and some other transport layer protocols).  The kernel doesn't look for port numbers when receiving packets for raw sockets.
3. The [`raw(7)` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/7/raw)‚ states:

   > All packets or errors matching the protocol number specified for the raw socket are passed to this socket.

   And it also states:

   > A raw socket can be bound to a specific local address using the `bind(2)` call. If it isn't bound, all packets with the specified IP protocol are received.

   Therefore you probably want to at least use different IP addresses for each end of the “connection”, and bind each end to its address.

   “But!” you say, “I'm using loopback!  I can only use the 127.0.0.1 address!”  Not so, my friend.  The entire 127.0.0.0/8 address block is reserved for loopback addresses; 127.0.0.1 is merely the most commonly-used loopback address.  Linux (but perhaps not other systems) responds to every address in the loopback block.  Try this in one window:

   ```
   nc -v -l 10150
   ```

   And then in another window:

   ```
   nc -s 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.2 10150
   ```

   You will see that you have created a TCP connection from 127.0.0.1 to 127.0.0.2. I think you can also bind your raw sockets to separate addresses.  Then, when you receive a packet, you can check whether it's from the other end's IP address to decide whether to process or discard it.

Comment: `select` is only useful for raw sockets when there are multiple NICs.

Comment: What if I have two raw sockets bound to different IP addresses on the same NIC?

Comment: I've never used raw sockets, but I would expect you would need to implement IP and separate them yourself.

Comment: @Potatoswatter IIRC, if you use `AF_INET, SOCK_RAW` then you are not responsible for the IP layer.  If you use `AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW`, then you are responsible for creating the entire packet, down to the MAC headers.

Comment: @Potatoswatter You only need to implement IP headers yourself if you choose to.  From the `raw(7)` man page: “The IPv4 layer generates an IP header when sending a packet unless the IP_HDRINCL socket option is enabled on the socket. When it is enabled, the packet must contain an IP header. For receiving the IP header is always included in the packet.”

Comment: Ah. It's not clear from the question how raw he wants to be. Or why raw is attractive at all :P . Anyway, I'll just mention that a virtual machine is the next best thing to a real network.

Comment: thanks @robmayoff you added so many things to my knowledge... :)

Comment: @Potatoswatter well, I am doing it because my teacher asked me to do so. And I want to implement all my header, ethernet, ip and tcp by myself. This much raw I want to be.

Comment: @user3542109 To emulate ethernet communication with one machine, you need a VM. Take a look at VirtualBox. It'll add a virtual NIC to the host OS. And, you won't need `select` except for multiple NIC support.

Answer (score 2):

Just curious, why do you want to use raw sockets?  Raw sockets (`AF_INET`, `SOCK_RAW`) allow you to send out "raw" packets, where you are responsible for crafting everything but the MAC and IP layers.

A1: There are no "connections" with raw sockets.  Just packets.

A2: There are no "ports" with raw sockets. Just packets.  "Port numbers" as we know them are part of the TCP or UDP protocols, both of which are above the level at which we work with raw sockets.

A3: This is not specific to raw sockets - you would have this issue regardless of your protocol selection. To really answer this, we would need to know much more about your proposed protocol, since right now, you're simply blasting out raw IP packets.

Comment: Thanks sir. I need to use it because my teacher asked me to do so.. :)